# Multi-account using Steam

Tags: multiplayer, steam

I want to test multiplayer features for my game on Steam.

Each player in the game must have an authenticated Steam account.

Is there a Steam feature to allow multiple developer accounts? Or if I were to do this would I need a separate PC to run Steam twice?

Comment: Steam accounts have unique usernames. Then, my educated guess is, two players with the same username are not allowed to play on the same server instance _at the very least_.